# Exibir ProgressDialog Spinner?

Tags: android, thread

Bem eu preciso fazer uma tarefa longa então fiz um ProgressDialog para informar tal tarefa, porém o spinner que deveria estar aparecendo parece oculto ou algo assim.

```
  protected void onPreExecute (){
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "Aguarde...",
                "Logando...");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
```

ja coloquei o codigo no onCreate() mas  mesmo assim n funcionou, alguma ideia do que seja?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente da Seguinte forma:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        progress.setTitle("Aguarde");
        progress.setMessage("Logando...");
        progress.show();
    }
```

No `onCreate`, chame sua Tarefa da seguinte forma:

```
 MinhaTarefa tarefa = new  MinhaTarefa();
 tarefa.execute((Void)null);
```

Este é apenas um exemplo, adapte caso sua `AsyncTask` use parametros para executar!

Comment: Tentei desta forma e continuou sem funcionar, mas acho que descobri o que estava causando isso, a cor do spinner talvez.

Comment: desculpe por fazelo perder seu tempo, mas nçao tinha percebi que o spinner estava branco que era a cor do meu tint, então foi só fazer um style pro ProgressDialog e deu certo

Comment: não é perda de tempo não! relaxa!